# How to increase resolution mode in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, screen-resolution

I am using HP Pavilion g6 and have installed Ubuntu 12.04. Maximum resolution my computer provides me in Ubuntu is 1366x768. But this is not enough for me, since Ubuntu has really large interface. I hate it when an iterface stretches along the screen. When I opened netbeans, editor part is just a little screen.

Is there any way to increase the capacity of my resolution. I have already tried this `xrandr --LVDS1 --scale 1.25x1.25`. It gave me the result that I wanted, however, this time, I can't move mouse further from a certain distance.

When I am on Windows, screen resolution can be up to 1960x1080. But in Ubuntu, not. How can I work this out? Or is there any other linux distro whose interface is smaller?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put an another screen to your computer or to change your computer to increase max resolution : It's screen's max resolution is 1366x768. so you cannot do anything in system configuration.

**Edit :**

After few search, your computer seems to be a laptop : which resolutions are 1366x768 max for a 15" and 1600x900 for a 17" . 
So this resolution cannot be support on your default screen : it's a material limitation. you can use better resolution with another screen connected on your laptop

Comment: But how can, in Windows, support up to 1960x1080 but in linux lesser?

Answer (score 0):

**The fix is explained for the Ubuntu running over VirtualBox.**
Run `xrandr` to show the supported modes of your monitor.

Then to select a mode use:

```
xrandr -s <"required-resolution">
```

in terminal.

The actual thing is that one should have guest additions installed and use The additional drivers to get maximum resolution in ubuntu.

Note:You may need the unity tweaker tool to perfect the fonts and other visual features there after.For that run

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```